# Hazelcast server with scala client issue

Tags: scala, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I am trying to setup hazelcast server and client on my local machine. I am also trying to connect to local Hazelcast server by scala-client.

For server I used below code,

```
import com.hazelcast.config._
import com.hazelcast.Scala._



object HazelcastServer {

def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

val conf = new Config
serialization.Defaults.register(conf.getSerializationConfig)
serialization.DynamicExecution.register(conf.getSerializationConfig)
val hz = conf.newInstance()


val cmap = hz.getMap[String, String]("test")
cmap.put("a","A")
cmap.put("b","B")


}
}
```

and hazelcast client as,

```
import com.hazelcast.Scala._
import client._
import com.hazelcast.client._
import com.hazelcast.config._


object Hazelcast_Client {

  def main(args:Array[String]): Unit = {

    val conf = new Config
    serialization.Defaults.register(conf.getSerializationConfig)
    serialization.DynamicExecution.register(conf.getSerializationConfig)
    val hz = conf.newClient()


    val cmap = hz.getMap("test")
    println(cmap.size())




  }

}
```

In my build.sbt,

```
libraryDependencies += "com.hazelcast" % "hazelcast" % "3.7.2"
libraryDependencies += "com.hazelcast" %% "hazelcast-scala" % "3.7.2"
```

I am getting below error and stuck in dependency issues.

```
Symbol 'type <none>.config.ClientConfig' is missing from the classpath.
[error] This symbol is required by 'value com.hazelcast.Scala.client.package.conf'.
[error] Make sure that type ClientConfig is in your classpath and check for conflicting dependencies with `-Ylog-classpath`.
[error] A full rebuild may help if 'package.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of <none>.config.
[error]     val conf = new Config
```

I referred [hazelcast](https://hazelcast.org/clients/scala/) documentation. I am not able to find any good hazelcast scala examples to understand the setup and to start playing with. If anybody can help in solving this issue, or share really good scala examples that would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I've done a Scala+Akka Hazelcast before. My build.sbt included

```
libraryDependencies += "com.hazelcast" % "hazelcast-all" % "3.7.2"
```

I seem to remember that hazelcast-all was required.